# DataFrame.Replace(r'regex', regex=True) not working

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column with individuals' names:

```
name
Mr. Salmon
Mr Salmon
Ms. Salmon
Mrs. Salmon
Mrs Salmon
...
```

I would like to remove all the honorifics. I compiled the following regex at regex101.com and confirmed all the matches.

```
(^[Mm]([Rr]|[Ss]|[Xx]|[Rr][Ss]|[Ii][Ss]+)\.?\s)|(^[Mm][Ii][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr]\.?\s)|(^[Mm][Ii][Ss]+[Uu][Ss]\.?\s)
```

I am using the replace method on the names dataframe to remove the regex matches with nothing. I am using the following code:

```
names_nohf = names.replace(r'(^[Mm]([Rr]|[Ss]|[Xx]|[Rr][Ss]|[Ii][Ss]+)\.?\s)|(^[Mm][Ii][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr]\.?\s)|(^[Mm][Ii][Ss]+[Uu][Ss]\.?\s)', regex = True)
```

This, however, is not returning the desired names and is in fact making no changes at all. Could someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: maybe you have to add value which you want to put in place of found strings - ie. `replace("old", "new")` - and then uses empty string as new string.

Comment: The replace method assumes None as the default argument for ‘new’ as per this documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: when I test with `None` then it doesn't work but if I put empty string then it works

Answer (score 1):

Use empty string as new value

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'X': ['Mr A', 'Mr B', 'Mr C']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df = df.replace('Mr', '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Result

```
      X
0  Mr A
1  Mr B
2  Mr C

    X
0   A
1   B
2   C
```